# error 6 overflow, while creating an XML DOMdocument through iteration

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I use an `elem_count = Range("Nalog!b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row= Range("Nalog!b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to find out how many rows of elements I have in my sheet and then use this in `For` loop which in turn appends elements, row by row, to an XML file which is used to create some objects in AutoCAD.
The code I present works perfectly for my needs until `elem_count > 100` then I get error 6 overflow.
How do I prevent this from happening?
The code:

```
For i = 1 To elem_count
    public_i = i + 15
    ins_point = ins_point + 300
    m_xml_varstring.s_varstring

    Set elem_root_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("Set")
    elem_root_BuilderList.appendChild elem_root_Set

    Set att_LineNo = DOKUMENT.createAttribute("LineNo")
    att_LineNo.NodeValue = i
    elem_root_Set.setAttributeNode att_LineNo

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("Pname")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set
            elem_Set.Text = Range("Nalog!es" & i + 15).Value

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("Count")
            elem_Set.Text = Str(Range("Nalog!k" & i + 15))
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("PVarString") 'VARSTRING
            elem_Set.Text = m_xml_varstring.PVarString
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("ARTICLE_TEXT_INFO1")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("ARTICLE_TEXT_INFO2")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("ARTICLE_PRICE_INFO1")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("ARTICLE_PRICE_INFO2")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("ARTICLE_PRICE_INFO3")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("Pinsertion")
            elem_Set.Text = Str(ins_point) & ".00,0.00,0.00"
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("POrntation") ' STA?
            elem_Set.Text = "0.00,0.00,0.00"
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("DeliveryPeriod")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("LIEFERANT")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("Mengenrabatt")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set

            Set elem_Set = DOKUMENT.createElement("MengenrabattAbs")
            elem_root_Set.appendChild elem_Set


Next
```

Comment: What kind of variable is elem_count?

Comment: It is an integer. As far as i know '.Row' returns an integer.

Comment: Have you tried defining it as long?

Comment: No I Haven't I'll try and let know.

Comment: Do the same with public_i and ins_point...

Comment: Okay ill give it a shot!

Comment: Okay this worked. Thanks a Bunch  N. Pavon!

Comment: I added the answer so that you can accept it and the question is marked as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define:

```
Dim elem_count As Long
Dim public_i As Long
Dim ins_point As Long
```